# %Calendar.AmbiguousDateTime{possible_date_times calendar Elixir

Tags: calendar, elixir

I have been doing date time conversions using `Calendar` everything was working fine for last 4 months but all of sudden am starting some strange behaviour in this, 
what am doing is

```
1..total_days |> Enum.reduce(start_date, fn _i, acc ->
  day_of_week = acc |> Calendar.Date.day_of_week_name
  rec_head = get_head_tail(schedule[day_of_week])
  rec_head |> Enum.each(fn(x) ->
    iterate(x, acc, timezone) |> t_download(interval, t_agent)
  end)
  acc |> Calendar.DateTime.to_erl |> IO.inspect |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!(timezone, {123456, 6}) |> IO.inspect |> Calendar.DateTime.add!(86400)
end)
```

And the

```
acc |> Calendar.DateTime.to_erl |> IO.inspect |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!(timezone, {123456, 6}) |> IO.inspect |> Calendar.DateTime.add!(86400)
```

give output as

```
{{2016, 10, 27}, {1, 0, 0}}
%Calendar.DateTime{abbr: "IST", day: 27, hour: 1, min: 0, month: 10, sec: 0,
 std_off: 3600, timezone: "Europe/Dublin", usec: {123456, 6}, utc_off: 0,
 year: 2016}
{{2016, 10, 28}, {1, 0, 0}}
%Calendar.DateTime{abbr: "IST", day: 28, hour: 1, min: 0, month: 10, sec: 0,
 std_off: 3600, timezone: "Europe/Dublin", usec: {123456, 6}, utc_off: 0,
 year: 2016}
{{2016, 10, 29}, {1, 0, 0}}
%Calendar.DateTime{abbr: "IST", day: 29, hour: 1, min: 0, month: 10, sec: 0,
 std_off: 3600, timezone: "Europe/Dublin", usec: {123456, 6}, utc_off: 0,
 year: 2016}
{{2016, 10, 30}, {1, 0, 0}}
```

But on the last date and time instead of giving me right output as it is giving above, It is giving this

```
 {:ambiguous, %Calendar.AmbiguousDateTime{possible_date_times: [%Calendar.DateTime{abbr: "GMT", day: 30, hour: 1, min: 0, month: 10, sec: 0, std_off: 0, timezone: "Europe/Dublin", usec: {123456, 6}, utc_off: 0, year: 2016}, %Calendar.DateTime{abbr: "IST", day: 30, hour: 1, min: 0, month: 10, sec: 0, std_off: 3600, timezone: "Europe/Dublin", usec: {123456, 6}, utc_off: 0, year: 2016}]}}
```

Am totally unknown to that reason as It was working fine but all of sudden its giving me these errors. any help?

UPDATE: am using https://github.com/lau/calendar Calendar.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using [lau/calendar](https://github.com/lau/calendar), might be worth it to point it out in the question.

Comment: Thanks doing it..

Comment: @nietaki Btw Just saw your are from MainFrame, One my X Fellow colleague is also in Mainframe,  Milos Mosic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.AmbiguousDateTime.html), this happens when the input time you provide is ambiguous:

> AmbiguousDateTime provides a struct which represents an ambiguous time
>   and date in a certain time zone. These structs will be returned from
>   the DateTime.from_erl/2 function when the provided time is ambiguous.
>
> AmbiguousDateTime contains two DateTime structs. For instance they can
>   represent both a DST and non-DST time. **If clocks are turned back an
>   hour at 2:00 when going from summer to winter time then the “wall
>   time” between 1:00 and 2:00 happens twice. One of them is on DST and
>   one of them is not.**

This seems to be your case. The times output are 1 a.m. `Europe/Dublin` time, and the 1 a.m. occurs twice on October 30th 2016: the second time is when at 2 a.m. you turn the clock back when Daylight Savings Time ends.

It seems like you can use the [disamb/2](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.AmbiguousDateTime.html#disamb/2) function to disambiguate the result you're getting.

Comment: But why it started happening when it was working fine for last 5 months

Comment: And which zone_abbr I should select? IST or GMT? If that's the case then i can select one value from the list will this make any difference?

Comment: I don't know what date ranges your code is running on, my guess would be it just never happened to run into this edge case before - it just happens just for one hour every year.

Comment: Okay fine the issue in only coming when start date is before October, I totallly get that BUT what about selecting one of the value? The only difference is IST and GMT and `std_off: 3600` in disamb, what zone I should select?

Comment: It's your call which of the results suits your use-case best: the one with `std_off: 3600` would be the "first occurrence" of 1 a.m. on that day, still with summer time, the one with `std_off: 0` would be the "second occurrence", without the summer time offset anymore.